# What statistical test (using R) can reveal relationships between 5 factors in randomized block design?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, inference, manova, blocking

I'm at a loss as to how I can efficiently obtain p-values in R for the relationships I am interested in exploring in my dataset.

Here is a picture summarizing the block design.
[image: each of 32 different treatments covers each of the 32 possible combinations for the inclusion or exclusion of 5 different microbial species (R;B;M;S;V) in said treatment. The first blocking factor is always R. The remaining 4 blocking factors (B;M;S;V) are randomized. There are 6 blocks, and so, 6 replicates for each of the 32 treatments.]

Various response variables measure plant yield (ex.: shoot weight, root weight, fruit harvested.)

I also have possible co-variables (ex.: position in the greenhouse) which Forward Selection with an RDA has shown significantly impacts the response variables, even though this impact is very minor overall.

My attempts at running a Tukey Test came out poorly because the number of relationships to test between 32 treatments is considerable, so the correction to the p-value makes everything insignificant. 
If I simply do a bar plot for all treatments for each variable, I can see that there ought to be some significantly different treatments.

Partial RDA also turned out inconclusive, as I am unable to use the results to distinguish anything such as whether or not, for instance, the presence of strain "M" in treatments with "B" significantly differs from treatments with "B" without "M".

I am uncertain how to perform MANOVA in R with 5 experimental variables such as this, and if it will answer my questions. References I can find only tend to have 2 levels.

Any advice on what analyses to use on this data are greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are all the variables you've collected related to the outcome a priori?

Comment: @DemetriPananos The variables describing the inclusion or exclusion of a microbial strain from the inoculum given to the plants are part of the experimental design; the experiment aims to investigate what effect this has on the response variables (various yield-related variables.) We do not know how significant it is, but they do have some effect, according to what we can see from bar plots (ex.: some treatments did twice as well as others on average on one or more response variables).